# Adding (2,) and (2, 1) arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to add arrays with shape (2,) and (2, 1), but it won't work. Example:

```
np.array([0, 1]).T + np.array([[0], [1]])
```

output:
`array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])`

expected output:
`array([[0], [2]])`

I tried reshaping and slicing but none of them worked for me...
How can I accomplish the expected result?

Comment: Show what doesn't work. A simple slice ought to do it

Comment: Broadcasting  a (2,) with (2,1) produces a (2,2).   If you want a (2,1) result, turn the first into a (2,1) .  Broadcasting will expand the (2,) to (1,2).

Comment: the broadcasting rules numpy employs might be difficult to guess but not complex.  The documentation is actually excellent, you can have a read here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
np.array([0, 1])[:,None] + np.array([[0], [1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.array([0, 1]).T.reshape(2, 1) + np.array([[0], [1]])
```